# Como obtener el valor de un TD creado a partir de un echo

Tags: php, javascript, html

les cuento. Estoy tratando de obtener el campo de un td, para ser exacto el primer td, el problema es que la tabla la estoy poblando desde otro archivo a partir de un echo, creo que al no existir, hipotéticamente, no reconoce la class del td que en este caso es .imgEditar.

Cree la tabla en el mismo documento y funciona correctamente, así que creo que ese debería ser el problema, necesito saber si existe la forma de lograrlo con este esquema o sencillamente deberé modificarlo ya que tambien recargo la tabla automaticamente cada cierto tiempo y al presionar el submit.

Lamento la burda forma en explicar, la verdad no tengo estudios de informática.

MUCHAS GRACIAS!

```html
<div class="form-group tabla table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar container">

        <table id="tablaProductos" class="table table-hover text-center">

            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Hora</th>
                    <th scope="col">Unidad</th>
                    <th scope="col">Servicio</th>
                    <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                    <th scope="col">Evaluar</th>
                    <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id='tablaincidente' class='text-center ' style="cursor: default !important">
                <!-- SE LLENA DESDE LA FUNCIÓN obtenerRegularidad()-->
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>



    <script  type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){           

            getNewData();

            setInterval(
                function(){
                    getNewData();
                }, 10000
            );

            // obtener el valor del td
            $('.imgEditar').on('dblclick', function(){
                var total = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
                alert(total);
            });

        })


        function getNewData(){
            var $this = $('#tablaincidente');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../BussinessLogic/cargarTablaRegularidad.php',
                success: function(r){ 
                    $this.replaceWith(r);
                }
            });
        }


    </script>
```

```php
// archivo cargarTablaRegularidad.php
    session_start();

    require_once('../DataAcess/regularidadDAClass.php');

    $driver = new mysqli_driver();
    $driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT;

    $regularidadDA = new regularidadDAClass();

    if(isset($_SESSION["sesionAdmin"]))
            $ingeniero = $_SESSION['sesionAdmin'];
        else
            $ingeniero = $_SESSION["sesionUser"];


    $regularidad = $regularidadDA->obtenerRegularidad($ingeniero);

    echo $regularidad;
```

```php
// archivo regularidadDAClass.php
require_once('conexionDAClass.php');

class regularidadDAClass{

    function obtenerRegularidad($rutIngeniero){

        $cnx = getConexion();

        $st2 = "SELECT * FROM regularidad WHERE ingeniero = '$rutIngeniero' ORDER BY evaluacion, fecha";

        $res2 = $cnx->query($st2);

        $cadena = "<tbody id='tablaincidente' class='text-center'>";

        while ($row1 = $res2->fetch_assoc()) {

            date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");

            $codigo = $row1['codigo'];

            $fecha = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()));

            $fechaeva = strtotime($row1['fechaevaluacion']);

            if( $fecha >= $fechaeva){

                $st1 = "UPDATE regularidad SET evaluacion = 'Evaluar' WHERE codigo = '$codigo' ";
                $res = $cnx->query($st1);

            }

            if($row1['evaluacion']=="Pendiente"){

                $dato = 'class="evaluar" style="color: #0787BB !important;"><div>'.$row1['evaluacion'].'</div>';
                $evaluarimg = '<div>-</div>';
            }
            else{
                $dato = 'class="evaluar" style="color: #FF0000 !important;""><div class="blink">'.$row1['evaluacion'].'</div>';
                $evaluarimg = '<img id="editar" class="imgEditar" style="margin-right: 10px; cursor:pointer;" src="img/editar.png" alt="Eliminar Producto">';
            }

            $fecharegistro = $row1['fecha'];

            $hora = date("H:i", strtotime($fecharegistro));

            $cadena=$cadena.'

            <tr">
                <td style="display:none;" scope="col">'.$row1['codigo'].'</td>
                <td scope="col">'.$hora.'</td>
                <td scope="col">'.$row1['unidad'].'</td>
                <td scope="col">'.$row1['serviciosentido'].'</td>
                <td scope="col"'.$dato.'</td>
                <td scope="col">'.$evaluarimg.'</td>
                <td scope="col"><img class="imgEliminar" style="margin-right: 10px; cursor:pointer;" src="img/boton-eliminar.png" alt="Eliminar Producto"></td>

             </tr>';

        }

        $cadena=$cadena.'</tbody>'; 

        echo $cadena;

    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor no edites tu pregunta para colocar ahí la solución, si la respuesta que te dieron fue la que te ayudó entonces lo correcto es marcarla como aceptada; esa es la mejor forma de mostrar gratitud a quien te ayudó

Comment: Le di a respuesta útil, si es a lo que te refieres, soy nuevo por lo que no aparecerá públicamente el voto. ademas, la respuesta me ayudo pero tuve que modificarla por eso la agregue al final, para que otros la vieran, si existe otra forma no lo sabia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí bien, tu problema es que en principio llenas la cáscara de la tabla mientras que el contenido sólo aparece después de una llamada Ajax.

Lo que ocurre es que efectivamente el elemento  no existe.

Aunque hayas puesto `$(document).ready(...)` el llamado a getData y la declaración del listener compiten en un mismo scope.

```
 // Cuando se dibuja la cáscara entra acá
 $(document).ready(function(){           

        // gatilla un llamado
        getNewData();

        // agenda otro llamado en 10s más
        setInterval(
            function(){
                getNewData();
            }, 10000
        );

        // declaro un listener en una celda que no exite
        $('.imgEditar').on('dblclick', function(){
            var total = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
            alert(total);
        });


        // 500ms después, se resuelve getNewData()

    });
```

Tu listener se declara antes que `getNewData` se resuelva. Y claro, si además vas a refrescar casa 10s, no basta con esperar cruzando los dedos a que la función se haya resuelto cuando declares el listener.

Lo que se hace en estos casos es aprovechar que:

- Los eventos en un elemento se propagan aguas arriba hasta el tope del documento (si alguien se molestara en suscribirse a ellos)
- El elemento  `#tablaProductos` sí existe desde un principio
- De los dos anteriores, le puedes pedir a `#tablaProductos` que te avise si alguna vez en la eternidad alguien pincha en una celda que formó parte de la iteración 5000 de `getData`

-

```
  $('#tablaProductos').on('dblclick', '.imgEditar', function(){
     var total = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
     alert(total);
  });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, logre solucionarlo con lo que me indicaste, la única diferencia es que pude obtener el dato desde el tr y no desde .imgEditar. De todas forma se pudo lograr. Gracias!